# How can i save an image in the MySQL DB - Code Given

Tags: java, mysql, image, spring-mvc

I am trying to save a file in the Database.

Here's my code.

```
public class DocumentForm {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1)
    private byte[] file;

    public byte[] getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(byte[] file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

...
}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "document", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String signup(@Valid @ModelAttribute DocumentForm documentForm, Errors errors, RedirectAttributes ra) {
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        return "document/document";
    }
    Document d = projectRepository.save(documentForm.createDoc());
    MessageHelper.addSuccessAttribute(ra, "document.success");
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

view

```
    <input type="file" name="file" class="btn"></input>
<button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
```

In the database:

It shows that the image is saved as a `BLOB`.

[image]

However, when i try to view the image, by clicking on `Open Value in Editor` in mySQL browser, What i see is only the name of the image file.

How can i save an image in the MySQL DB ? and how can i retrieve it and display on my View

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using Part class which can hold form data

Part filePart = request.getPart("image");

inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();

statement.setBlob(1, inputStream);

Answer (score 0):

The blob type is a binary field which houses the contents of any binary data. Since MySql browser probably doesn't know the type of the blob, all it can provide you with is the name. The data, should all still be there.

That said, I think you'll find that usually images are NOT stored in the database, and instead a reference to an image on the disk is stored. This is because databases are not very efficient for large binary stores.

Things you probably want to store in the database in order to appropriately reference an image:

1. The name of the image
2. The size of the image data
3. Maybe the dimensions
4. A canonical url that indicates where the server will return it from.

If you find yourself needing to stream an image via your servlet container (tomcat, jboss, w/e), then you can do so by creating a streaming html response. Something like this, where InputStream is the stream to the blob (binary) data:

```
 public void serveInputStreamByResponse(HttpServletResponse response, InputStream in) {
        try {
            FileCopyUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
          // do something
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();    // very important
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // do something
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you suggest is to save the image in the Drive and have the references saved in the DB ?

Comment: Yes. You'll find that to be more efficient since you can offload the serving of the images to your server (apache, nginx, etc) instead of making the servlet container handle it. Plus, just reading images from a db is not very efficient.